# Django: trouble with user_id field of UserProfile after migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I migrated my database from MySql to PostgreSQL, and, as I noticed that many tables weren't updated, some googling told me to do things like this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_table_id_seq OWNED BY my_table.id;
```

and things started to work. I had to do this for all my tables.

Then I realized that after creating a django.contrib.auth.model.User, and trying to create a UserProfile afterwards with a `post_save` hook, I would get an `IntegrityError` because the `user_id` foreign key is sent as null.

Here's the `query` and `args` (in Python) that is sent to PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "is_staff", "is_active", "is_superuser", "last_login", "date_joined") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) (u'apitest04', '', '', u'a@a.aa', 'sha1$9f796$69c88c635c8a53a91544765d7996747cf326cfec', False, True, False, u'2013-01-05 12:39:07.384198', u'2013-01-05 12:39:07.384198')

INSERT INTO "myapp_userprofile" ("user_id", "website", "job", "hobbies", "timezone", "about", "company_name", "company_description", "company_website", "retailer_country", "avatar", "default_license", "default_watermark_text", "default_watermark", "default_watermark_position", "default_watermark_opacity", "language") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) (None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 0, None, False, 0, 10, None)
```

I suppose what's happening is that the sequence id for `auth_user` is not advanced before the transaction is closed. I suspect that because the creation of the `User` is rolled back when the creation of the `UserProfile` fails, so they must be happening during the same transaction.

Is it possible that the `id` of the `User` is somehow not returned yet, because the transaction has not ended yet? And how do you propose I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, and it was happening because the `auth_user.id` sequence had no owner. This fixed it:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE auth_auth_id_seq OWNED BY auth_auth.id;
```